# Using Rasterio to save window image (as jpg)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, rasterio

I'm trying to open an jpg (01.jpg) using Python Rasterio and save the Window as a jpg
I can do it for 1 band, not not for the 3 bands of the RGB source image.
the issue is with the band rearranging.
below my code and the error :

Source shape (2000, 2000, 3) is inconsistent with given indexes 1

I tried to modify line code src = np.moveaxis(src, [0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0])
but I still have errors..
can you please offer advice ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

w =2000
h = 2000
tile = np.ones((w,h))
cv2.imwrite('tile.jpg', tile)

with rasterio.open('01.JPG') as src:
  src = src.read(window=Window(0, 0, w, h))
  show(src)

with rasterio.open('tile.jpg', 'w', driver='GTiff',width=w, height=h, count=1,dtype=src.dtype) as tile:
  src = np.moveaxis(src, [0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 0])
  tile.write(src)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to save a 3-band image (which you read from `01.JPG`) into a 1-band image (which you opened with `count=1`). `np.moveaxis` just shifts the axes positions, but you still have three axes (as the error message is telling you the shape is `(2000, 2000, 3)`).

If you want to save all three bands, but with changed order (possibly to create a [false-color/pseudocolor image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color)), you'd need to change `count=1` to `count=3`.

## If you need to write just one band

There are two ways to do that: you can read just one band when you read the `01.JPG` raster, [by passing the band index as the first argument to the `read()` function](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html?highlight=read#offsets-and-windows), or keep reading all three bands and [indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html) the band you want when you save, so you get an array with shape `(2000, 2000)` (probably `src[i]` if you want to read band `i`).

Note this index will start at zero, following numpy convention, instead of 1 when reading from rasterio (which follows [the GDAL convention of starting the band numbers at 1](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading.html#reading-datasets)).